# google in-app purches policy

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app

I hope that's the right place to ask (I couldn't find where else can I ask it).

I'm developing an app for couples counselor.
The idea of ​​the app is recording the consultation process, and every patient will be asked to download it.
The patient gets a username and password which will allow him to log into his private zone, where he can update his progress.
The user doesn't pay for the app, but for the consulting, and the app only helps recording and following the process.

The question is, does this app violate any of google policies?

Comment: You should add the 'android' tag to your question.

Comment: No one here can answer that question for you with 100% certainty. Ask Google or speak to a lawyer.